# удалить "пересечённые" дубликаты записей

Tags: сортировка, sed, sh, awk

Нужно удалить дубликаты записей, в которых пересекаются одинаковые значения из разных колонок.

К примеру вот что у меня есть (жирым я выделил ДУБЛИКАТЫ):

```
    meshnode-01 meshnode-04 100/100
    meshnode-01 meshnode-03 100/100
    meshnode-01 meshnode-05 81/82
    meshnode-01 meshnode-02 89/85
    meshnode-02 meshnode-05 100/100
    meshnode-02 meshnode-04 83/93 
    meshnode-02 meshnode-01 85/88
    meshnode-02 meshnode-03 97/97
    meshnode-03 meshnode-01 100/100
    meshnode-03 meshnode-04 83/72
    meshnode-03 meshnode-05 93/97
    meshnode-03 meshnode-02 95/97
```

То есть записи "meshnode-01 meshnode-03" и "meshnode-03 meshnode-01" в данном случае это дубликаты.
Вот что мне нужно получить:

```
    meshnode-01 meshnode-04 100/100
    meshnode-01 meshnode-05 81/82
    meshnode-02 meshnode-05 100/100
    meshnode-02 meshnode-04 83/93
    meshnode-02 meshnode-01 85/88
    meshnode-03 meshnode-01 100/100
    meshnode-03 meshnode-04 83/72
    meshnode-03 meshnode-05 93/97
    meshnode-03 meshnode-02 95/97
```

Пытался различные варианты сортировок, но всё бестолку, на ум приходит только засунуть всё в массив и "переворачивать" каждую запись, а затем построчно сравнивать каждую с оригиналом. Но это слишком сложно даже в мыслях, может есть идеи попроще?

Вот сам скрипт которым я получаю данный список:

```
#!/bin/bash

nodes="meshnode-01 meshnode-02 meshnode-03"

for a in ${nodes}
do
    while read line
    do
        echo "$a $line"
    done < ${a}.list
done
```

Значения хранятся в разных файлах:

```
ls -l *.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124 Apr 11 12:48 meshnode-01.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 123 Apr 11 12:48 meshnode-02.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 122 Apr 11 12:48 meshnode-03.list
```

UPDATE: сначала не стал добавлять колонку "link quality", а сейчас понял что её присутствие в примире ВАЖНО. В общем здесь нельзя просто свалить всё в одну кучу и отфильтровать одинаковое, так как присутствует третья колонка, которая должна быть привязана к записи.

Comment: слова в строке отсортируйте сначала, а потом уж удаляйте дубликаты строк.

Comment: А вот в таком виде?

Comment: убрал "shell". Мне не принципиально как именно, sed, sort, uniq, awk. Всё что угодно, как получить результат?

Comment: окей, сортируйте только два первых слова в строке. и по первым двум словам и ищите дубликаты. в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Хорошо, речь ведь идёт о потоке, как потом вернуть третью колонку на место, в соответствии с первоначальным положением?

Comment: может питоном это всё разобрать?

Comment: "третью колонку на место" - отсортируй в обратном порядке и она останется на месте

Comment: не удаляйте третье слово. и не придётся его «возвращать».

Comment: вот вам прототип: `поток | while read f1 f2 f3; do echo -n "$f1 $f2" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ' '; echo "$f3"; done | sort -u -k1,2`. улучшайте на здоровье. // первый tr вместо `\n` прямо в аргументе программы echo — на случай posix-овской версии программы echo.

Comment: тут ещё момент что на третьем месте циферки надо менять местами

Comment: *речь ведь идёт о потоке* — кстати, о потоке у вас в вопросе не упоминается. и если это действительно непрерывный поток информации, то это совсем другой уровень сложности. ведь решения с сортировкой просто теряют смысл: надо держать в памяти (кэше?) уже накопившиеся строки и искать дубликаты для очередной поступившей строки «на ходу».

Comment: Спасибо, отлегло, пока что годится так.

Comment: В потоке можно только через хеширование и обработку коллизий. Самый простой способ, записывать строки в Git репозиторий. Элементарно на Shell имплементировать.

Answer (score 0):

На питоне через словарь с ключами

```
import glob
lines=[]
for fname in glob.glob('*.list'):
    lines += open(fname,'r').readlines()


lines = [ l.split() for l in lines ]
lmap = dict()

for m1,m2,ccq in lines:
    lmap[tuple(sorted([m1,m2]))] = m1,m2,ccq


for v in lmap.values():
    print(*v)
```